# How is the t-statistic value calculated in GEO2R or Bioconductor?

Tags: statistics, limma, geoquery

I was trying to calculate t-statistics using Python's `scipy` and `numpy as np`-

```py
scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats(
    NP.mean(x[['GSM1224991', 'GSM1224992']]),
    NP.std(x[['GSM1224991', 'GSM1224992']]),
    len(['GSM1224991', 'GSM1224992']),
    NP.mean(x[['GSM1224993', 'GSM1224994']]),
    NP.std(x[['GSM1224993', 'GSM1224994']]),
    len(['GSM1224993', 'GSM1224994']),
)
```

For example in the dataset given below, `GSM1224991 & GSM1224992` are in first group and `GSM1224993 & GSM1224994` form second group.

```
ID_REF,GSM1224991,GSM1224992,GSM1224993,GSM1224994
148000,6.436150368369428,6.499787040655854,4.430816798843313,3.0819099697950434
```

Here is the calculation given in GEO2R analysis for the same reference but while I calculate t test it is `0.029630766122806237` instead of `-0.33768` something as shown below.

```
ID  adj.P.Val   P.Value t   B   logFC
148000  1   0.001426    -9.44   -0.33768    -2.513
```

How to calculate t-stat here? Or considering single row is wrong approach?

Answer (score 1):

That is not trivial. GEO2R uses the Bayesian linear model-based framework `limma` https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html for the analysis. I doubt you can easily and meaningfully implement the relevant code in Python without a major effort and notable background knowledge. The user guide https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf has background information plus links to the relevant papers. Don't try to analyze things by hand, use expert software. If it is not significant, well, then it is not significant. A 2vs2 comparison is strongly underpowered, therefore lack of DEGs are not unexpected, especially for microarrays.

Comment: I am learning R and I will make transition to R for sure but I want to understand each and every step and function to satisfying my quest.